# Tables in SQL Server database are not auto-created

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa, glassfish

I'm trying to auto-create tables from Java in database on Microsoft SQL Server 2012. I'm using JPA and there is my persistence.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="PU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>DS</jta-data-source>
    <class>msg.Message</class>
    <class>msg.Response</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

JDBC Connection Pool on glassfish ping with succeed (additional properties

URL: jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1;databaseName=test;instanceName=SQLEXPRESS;
User: user
Password: password
PortNumber: 1433 )

header of Message.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "message", schema = "xxx_msg")
public class Message implements Serializable {

@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;
@JoinColumn(name = "sender_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
@ManyToOne
private Person senderId;
```

There are no errors on build or deploy, database is up but no tables are created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed

I had to create schemas with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio first (my database -> new Query -> CREATE SCHEMA xxx_msg )